# jquery tablesorter vertical scroll not working

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, tablesorter

I am using jquery tablesorter table in my application. I want to add a maximum height for tbody and overflow-y scroll.

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 

</tbody> 
</table>
```

I add

```
.tablesorter thead{
display:block;
}
.tablesorter tbody{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block ;
}
```

But its not taking...is there any way to add this functionality to tablesort?

Comment: sorry for the missing dot(.), its not working still

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `.` before class name of the table.

Your CSS code should look like this,

```
.tablesorter thead{
display:block;
}
.tablesorter tbody{
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block ;
}
```

It should be `.tablesorter tbody` instead of `tablesorter tbody`.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ybb7aw47/